# Breeze - Local cache flushed when creating an entity

Tags: breeze

It seems to me the local cache for the current table is flushed when creating an entity ( manager.createEntity(current table))
Is this how it should work? I think this is strange behaviour.

TJ

Comment: Need to provide some additional code so we can understand what you mean by current table and by flushed.  This is not the case and Breeze does not work like this, and in fact current table is not a valid parameter to pass into createEntity, it should be something like manager.createEntity('current table'); if anything

Comment: You right. It should be manager.createEntity('current table'); But you are sure breeze does not behave like this?

Comment: 100% sure that it does not, createEntity simply adds a new entity to the entityManager.

Comment: I think a was triked by the projection ability in Breeze. Thanks for your help PW Kad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TJ - my bet is that your entities were never in cache to begin with. You queried something perhaps (used a projection/select?) which returned data you can use ... but not entities that Breeze can cache.  I believe this is what PW Kad is hinting at.

Can you confirm?